# A function to produce unary representation

Tags: scheme

I am supposed to write a function that takes a non-negative number and produces its unary representation.
I am new to scheme programming. Can somebody get me out of this?

Comment: Yuga, people will help you if you do some effort before you ask question. Did you try to read any documentation or google how to do it ?

Comment: First warm up. Make a function that given `n` produces the digits of n. Now think about how to change that function.

Comment: Are you sure you want the *unary* representation? Unary is very easy (almost trivial) to generate with recursion.

Comment: Thanks @seogaard . I tried it again and successful in doing that.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks . I tried it again and successful in doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(define int-unary (lambda (n) (if (= n 0) 'z (cons 's (int-unary(n-1))))))

This is the thing i got finally and it gave me the desired output.